# Obtener fecha y hora del servidor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto con vue js en quasar y quisiera saber como podría guardar en una variable la fecha y hora del servidor, no sé como se debe realizar y me gustaría si me pudieran ayudar

Comment: ¿Tienes código en el backend? De ser así sería bueno que especificaras el lenguaje que utilizas y un [mcve] de cómo retornas la información, de este modo será más fácil que otros usuarios puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma es simplemente haciendo un `fetch`. La fecha y hora del servidor es devuelta en los headers HTTP, si es una petición CORS, es necesario agregar `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date` como header en la respuesta del servidor:

```
fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/").then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.headers.get("date"));
});
```